# Web read serial number GUID

Tags: c#, jquery, web, guid

How to get a unique identification from harddisk, motherboard etc from a web-application. I know that this is not possible to do directly.

I´m working in a company with a lot of personal information and the employees use a web-application, that I have developed in aspx.net, of course with login and https, but because of new rules from the government, this is not secure enough anymore.

So to solved this, the company have decided that we have to make some kind of whitelisting of computer, that means that every computer have to use a unique key (GUID) based on the computer's hardware to login to our web application.

But how to do that from web (aspx.net, javascript, jquery), can I make some kind of App (or a Winform program), and next time our employees try to login, they have to install the App/application, and then the aspx.net application can call this program and return the GUID to the login service (WCF-service), how to do that?

I have been working with c#, Winforms, Silverlight, aspx.net, javasript, jquery etc. for many years, but this year I have to find out how to developing Apps (cross platform), so if you have an example/link in other than those mentioned language, this would be fine too

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at this [Retrieving Hardware Identifiers in C# with WMI](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030511.asp).

By using classes such as `ManagementObject` and `ManagementClass` you will be able to get the properties of your computer's hardware.

Note that the processor ID itself is not unique, you might want to consider a combination of hardware IDs as your unique key.

ex:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return processorId from first CPU in machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>[string] ProcessorId</returns>
    public string GetCPUId()
    {
        string cpuInfo =  String.Empty;
        string temp=String.Empty;
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach(ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if(cpuInfo==String.Empty) 
            {// only return cpuInfo from first CPU
                cpuInfo = mo.Properties["ProcessorId"].Value.ToString();
            }             
        }
        return cpuInfo;
    }
```

Then you can create your own browser application to access your company's website. Fetch these IDs and pass them for security purposes.

Comment: I can't use this, because if I run this in a web-application, it just return the cpu-id from the server. But I could make a small program and install it on the Client-pc, but how can I call it from web

Comment: There must be one or more out there who knows something about how to do.
Or do I really have to do it like old fashioned ways, make a Winforms program that reads the hardware and make a GUID and then the program calls the web.application. 
I know there is a lot of new technologies, like Cordova, Ionic, Win-app etc. but I don't know if I can use any of them for my purpose, and I don't have time now to find out.

Comment: @quickKli sorry for not being clear. Run this code in the DIY browser you made in order to access the company website. I'm no expert but I'm just giving light to the matter. You should probably pass this a parameter on the user login page even before the user enters his/her credential. Control things from there.

Comment: That really help, NOT. Is it a joke? (D)o (I)t (Y)ourself browser :-)

Comment: @quickKli don't think too much about it the 'DIY' part. All you need is a browser like the WebBrowserControl in WinForms. You just need the app to fetch the hardware ids to create your unique key.